# Selenium quasar app test element "click" issue

Tags: selenium, pytest, quasar

I have an app made with Quasar. I make e2e tests with python selenium using firefox. I log in and then would like to logout. To perform this I need as usually click on profile icon to show the menu and select `Logout`.

[image: Profile menu]

The issue is that whatever I tried the menu doesn't appear. The code looks as follows.

```py
@pytest.mark.nondestructive
def test_must_login_and_logout_properly(logged_in_selenium, wait):
    driver = logged_in_selenium
    avatar = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//header//img[@alt="Profile image"]/ancestor::button/parent::span')))
    # "natively" via selenium
    ActionChains(driver).pause(1).move_to_element(avatar).click().perform()
    # via javascript
    driver.execute_script('document.evaluate(\'//header//img[@alt="Profile image"]/ancestor::button/parent::span\', document).iterateNext().dispatchEvent(new Event("click"))')
```

The above code doesn't work UNTIL I really click this element with the mouse. By putting `time.sleep(10)` at first line in test function and click. After that any method via `avatar.click()` or `execute_script(...)` works fine.

I also have an option to use PyAutoGUI to find the avatar on the screen and perform that click, but I don't like this variant.

-- UPDATE

I found out why it behaves like this, but still don't know how to work this around. Initially (after page load) `click` event handler is not attached to `//header//img[@alt="Profile image"]/ancestor::button/parent::span` element. It only appears after manual click in this area.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would question the XPath. Talk to your developer which element actually needs to receive the click.

Comment: I found the exact element in console by inspecting events.

Comment: That is fine. My question (to the developer) would be: Is that the correct element that is watching for that click event? I would imagine the `ancestor::button` would seem more appropriate, rather than the `parent::span`. But you did not provide the DOM, so this is just a guessing game.

Comment: @SiKing I agree. I think this doesn't relate to app developer but to Quasar devs. As Quasar is on top of Vue many auxiliary elements are generated regardless the application code. The link to the app is https://testnet.mindsync.ai.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share a link to this page, so I can only guess.
I would try to:

1. Wait for element visibility, not just existance.
2. Try to remove `click` from `ActionChains` action.
3. Add a short delay between moving to the element and click on it..
   Still not sure, but possibly this will work

```
avatar = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//header//img[@alt="Profile image"]/ancestor::button/parent::span')))

ActionChains(driver).pause(1).move_to_element(avatar).perform()
time.sleep(0.2)
avatar.click()
```

**UPD**
Try this:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='q-avatar']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Logout']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please see the updated part of the question. It looks like the issue regards to the dynamic nature of vue/quasar.

Comment: Have to see that web page, it's too difficult to guess about what you haven't see

Comment: Thank you, this works. Turns out that it's enough to click twice `//header//img[@alt="Profile image"]/ancestor::button/parent::span` to make menu appear.

Comment: I'm not sure clicking twice is a better / correct way to do it. I just imitated exactly the user's flow: click on avatar and when the menu is opened click on logout element.

Comment: Actually your code clicked element twice. The first one is `'//header//img[@alt="Profile image"]/ancestor::button/parent::span'` and the second is `div[@class='q-avatar']` that is the child of first. That is because of Initially (after page load) click event handler is not attached to `//header//img[@alt="Profile image"]/ancestor::button/parent::span` element. It only appears after manual click in this area. I suppose `window.click()` attaches event handler to this element.

Comment: I never mentioned `'//header//img[@alt="Profile image"]/ancestor::button/parent::span'` in my code at all... My code contains only 2 element clicks.

Comment: In first part of answer. If I only use updated (second) part of code it doesn't work

Comment: The first answer was written based on your code provided here only, without seeing the web site while the updated answer is given after seeing the web site.

Comment: Ok, second part doesn't work if used alone

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it was necessary to click the element twice. Due to maybe Quasar implementation detail.

```py
@pytest.mark.nondestructive
def test_must_login_and_logout_properly(logged_in_selenium, wait):
    driver = logged_in_selenium
    avatar = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//header//img[@alt="Profile image"]/ancestor::button/parent::span')))
    ActionChains(driver).pause(1).move_to_element(avatar).click().pause(0.5).click().perform()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Logout']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[text()="You have logged out"]')))
```